# Can not install npm install @here/maps-api-for-javascript --save

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I can not install Maps API for node.js, according to this manual
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.20.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started-bundling.html

PS K:\Gran-canar\NODE-HERE\first-project> npm install @here/maps-api-for-javascript --save
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@here%2fmaps-api-for-javascript - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@here/maps-api-for-javascript@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alvares\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-04T03_04_24_998Z-debug.log
PS K:\Gran-canar\NODE-HERE\first-project>

Comment: did you successfully add HERE to your npm config?

Answer (score 7):

For me this worked

```
npm install @here/maps-api-for-javascript --registry=https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/api/npm/maps-api-for-javascript/
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an old post so it is probably too late to help the OP but From your error, it looks you missed running this line:

```
npm config set @here:registry https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/api/npm/maps-api-for-javascript/
```

As `npm install @here/anything` should not be checking `HTTP://registry.npmjs.org/` for the module files as they do not exist there.